# How to enforce backwards compatibility with View

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How could I apply View to enforce backwards compatibility with old queries that rely on old schema if the following change happens:

```
T(A1(key), A2)
```

to

```
T(A1(key), A2(key))
```

Basically we would make second attribute to be a joined key with first attribute.

Is there any standard way of doing it across diff sql languages?
If not I am interested in SQLite/SQLite3.

Thanks you!

Comment: What you have shown is not SQL. What, specifically, is the actual change?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that you'd treat this no different to a table, other than not having to worry about the actual data.

That is include it in the older schema to work with the older schema and then upgrade it to the new schema along with the tables by using

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS your_view; 
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS your_view .............;
```

For other SQL, again as for tables, you may find it simpler to just use the often more extensive ALTER commands.

Without specifics it's hard to say whether or not a single standard method could be adopted.